# What the meaning of `uint4korr` in the MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I notice there is a macro `uint4korr` in the MySQL/MariaDB source code.

> include/byte_order_generic.h

I merely understand this macro is correlated with byte order. But I looked for the comments about this macro, found nothing. I don't know the meaning of the suffix `korr`. What does the abbreviation express?

I want to know why the code implements like this? What are the effects on different platforms?

Comment: Here is the source code link:  https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.11/include/byte_order_generic.h

Answer (score 2):

"korr" is an abbreviation for "Korrekt" of the phonic and meaning equivalent of the English word "Correct".

The purpose of the code is to provide a uniform byte order of storage and communication components so the storage files are portable between different endian architectures without conversion, and the client/server communication doesn't need to know which endian the other architecture is.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the related Swedish verb is [korrigera](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/korrigera), to correct. `uint4korr()` is kind of the opposite of `ntohl()`, because it will swap the bytes on a big-endian architecture and not little-endian.

Somewhat related to this, the InnoDB storage engine stores its data in big-endian byte order, so that a simple `memcmp()` can be used for comparing keys. (It also inverts the sign bit of signed integers due to this.) The InnoDB function `mach_read_from_4()` is basically `ntohl()` combined with a 32-bit load via an unaligned pointer. Recent versions of GCC and clang impress me by translating that into the IA-32 or AMD64 instructions `mov` and `bswap` or simply `movbe`.